# Plotting hypotrochoids using Python

Tags: python, debugging, plot, geometry

I have been trying to use a computer to plot some [hypotrochoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotrochoid), but I've run into some issues. For those that are unfamiliar, the parametric equations of a hypotrochoid are:

```
x(theta) = (R - r)cos(theta) + d*cos((R-r)/r*theta)
```

and

```
y(theta) = (R - r)sin(theta) - d*sin((R-r)/r*theta)
```

The definition on Wikipedia of a hypotrochoid can further explain:

> A hypotrochoid is a roulette traced by a point attached to a circle of
>   radius r rolling around the inside of a fixed circle of radius R,
>   where the point is a distance d from the center of the interior
>   circle.

So a hypotrochoid with values `r = d = 1` and `R = 3`, should look something like this:

[image]

But that is certainly not what I am ending up with using my computing method. My hypotrochoid (with the same values) looks something like this:

[image]

Since the x and y values are determined by a function of x and y at angle `theta` I assumed I could simply loop through the values of `theta` from 0 to 2pi and calculate the x and y values separately at certain intervals, then plot the coordinate in polar form (where `r**2 = x**2 + y**2`), but I suppose I thought wrong. Maybe my formulae are wrong but I just checked it over with a few guys over at [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741997/problem-plotting-hypotrochoids-using-a-computer?noredirect=1#comment1547145_741997) and we couldn't figure out what's wrong. What methods SHOULD be used to calculate a hypotrochoid if my methods are wrong?

Here is the code:

```
class _BaseCurve(event.EventAware):

    # This is a basic curve class from which all other curves inherit from (as
    # you will see below with the Hypotrochoid class). Basically what happens is
    # each new curve class must implement a function (relation) to calculate the
    # radius of the equation at each angle interval, then plots the equation in
    # other code elsewhere.

    def __init__(self, radius, init_angle, end_angle, speed, acceleration, *args, **kwargs):

        # Initialize geometric data...
        self.radius = radius

        # Initialize curve start and end angles...
        self.init_angle = init_angle
        self.end_angle = end_angle

        # Initialize time-based curve attributes...
        self.speed = speed
        self.accel = acceleration
        self.current_pos = 0

        # Initialize defaults...
        self.max_speed = inf
        self.min_speed = neginf

        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def set_max_speed(self, speed):
        """Set the maximum speed the path can achieve."""
        if speed < self.min_speed:
            errmsg = "Max speed cannot be less than min speed."
            raise ValueError(errmsg)
        self.max_speed = speed

    def set_min_speed(self, speed):
        """Set the minimum speed the path can achieve."""
        if speed > self.max_speed:
            errmsg = "Min speed cannot be greater than max speed."
            raise ValueError(errmsg)
        self.max_speed = speed

    def set_acceleration(self, acceleration):
        """Set a new acceleration for the path."""
        self.accel = acceleration

    def move(self):
        """Progress the path forward one step.

        The amount progressed each time (curve).move is called
        depends on the path's speed parameter and the distance
        (i.e. angle_difference) it has to travel. The calculation
        is as follows:

        angle = angle_difference * current_position + init_angle

        Where current_position is the position incremented by the
        set speed in (curve).move().
        """
        self.current_pos += self.speed
        if self.accel != 1:
            new_speed = self.speed * self.accel
            self.speed = max(min(new_speed, self.max_speed), self.min_speed)

    def angle(self):
        """Return the angle of the curve at the current position."""
        return self.angle_difference * self.current_pos + self.init_angle

    def relation(self):
        """Return the relationship of the current angle to the radius.

        This is a blank function left to be filled in by subclasses of
        _BasicCurve. The return value for this function must be a function
        (or lambda expression), of which that function's return value should
        be the radius of the curve at the current position. The parameters of
        the return equation should be as follows:

        (Assuming `r` is the function representing the relation):

        radius = r(current_angle, *args, **kwargs)

        Where *args and **kwargs are the additional *args and **kwargs specified
        upon initializing the curve.
        """
        return NotImplemented

    def position(self):
        """Calculate the position on the curve at the current angle.

        The return value of this function is the coordinate in polar
        form. To view the coordinate in cartesian form, use the
        `to_cartesian` function. # Ignore the `to_cartesian` function in this code snippet, it simply converts polar to cartesian coordinates.

        NOTE: This function requires self.relation to be implemented.
        """
        r = self.relation()
        theta = self.current_angle

        args = self.args
        kwargs = self.kwargs

        radius = self.radius*r(theta, *args, **kwargs)
        return radius, theta

    @property
    def angle_difference(self):
        """The difference between the start and end angles specified."""
        return (self.end_angle - self.init_angle)

    @property
    def current_angle(self):
        """The current angle (specified by self.current_pos)."""
        return self.angle_difference * self.current_pos + self.init_angle

Curve = _BaseCurve

class Hypotrochoid(Curve):
    def relation(self):
        def _relation(theta, r, R, d):
            x = (R - r)*math.cos(theta) + d*math.cos((R - r)/r * theta)
            y = (R - r)*math.sin(theta) - d*math.sin((R - r)/r * theta)
            return (x**2 + y**2)**(1/2)
        return _relation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mistake to transform x,y and theta to polar form for output. Theta is parameter of parametric equation, it is not polar angle of curve point (really it is polar angle of small circle center)

So x and y are ready-to use Descartes' coordinates. Just plot this point for ever step. This is Delphi test that draws exactly what you wanted (Canvas.Pixels[x, y] draws a point with (x,y) coordinates)

```
   R := 120;
   rr := 40;
   d:= 40;
   for i := 0 to 999 do begin
     a := i * 2 * Pi / 1000;
     y := 200 + Round((R - rr) * sin(a) - d*sin((R-rr)/rr*a));
     x := 200 + Round((R - rr) * cos(a) + d*cos((R-rr)/rr*a));
     Canvas.Pixels[x, y] := clRed;
   end;
```

Comment: Computationally, what is happening when I transform (x**2 + y**2)**(1/2) and theta to polar form and then back out to cartesian form? What is causing it to screw up in specific?

Comment: theta is not polar angle of (x,y) point. True polar angle for this point is atan2(y, x) .

Comment: OHHH that makes so much sense! Thank you!